# For DocuSign integration, is there an alternative to manually adding each Redirect URI to our API Key?

Tags: docusignapi

As part of the Code Grant authentication process described [here](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant), an integrated application passes a "redirect URI" to DocSign.  Each redirect URI must be defined in the Admin / API Key area of our DocuSign account.

Our customers will tend to each have different URIs, adding the URI for every customer installation, and updating them on changes, will be a burden.

Is there an alternative?  For instance:

- Is there a way to set our account to accept all URIs that match a certain pattern, with a wild card? (The filename will be consistent; the server names/paths will not.)
- Is there a way we can automate (through the REST API) the adding or modifying URIs in our account.
- There is a checkbox, “This is a mobile app”, on that page above the list of URIs.  What does it do?  Does it help us at all?

Answer (score 0):

- no there's no way to do that per OAuth protocol they must be defined.
- These APIs are not currently public
- This checkbox was removed

OAuth requires (For security purposes) a url that matches the url you have, so you'll have to ensure it's updated for all your customers.